# how to make my admin privileged application to run on startup

Tags: c#, startup, uac, administrator

I created an application which request user for admin privilege and i'm trying to make the program run on startup but its not working, am i missing any thing.

here what i did
1) adding a registry key

```
RegistryKey rkApp = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
```

2) second is creating a .lnk file and adding into the startup folder

both method working fine when i turn of the admin privilege (i.e) in app.manifest file

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

'highestavailable' to 'asInvoker'